# differential equation $y'\cos2x-y''\sin2x-y'''=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Here is differential equation $y'\cos2x-y''\sin2x-y'''=0$

Seems like I need to make a degree lower using substitution, then I get:

$y'' = y \cos2t - y'\sin2t $

What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After repeated attempts, I find $y_1(t)=\sin t$ is a solution.

Moreover, let $y(t)=z(t)y_1(t)$, we have $\sin t\ z''(t)+2\cos t\ (1+\sin^2 t)z'(t)=0$. Let $u(t)=z'(t)$, then we can conclude that $u(t)=C_1\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}\cos 2t}}{\sin^2 t},\ z(t)=\int u(t)dt,\ y(t)=(C_1\int \frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}\cos 2t}}{\sin^2 t}dt+C_2)\sin t$.